Change of variable, u = y/x
I am working on a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{\frac{x}{y}} + \frac{y}{x}$. My intuition is to perform a change of variable by letting  $u(x) = \frac{y}{x}$
However, I am having trouble figuring out what $\frac{du}{dx}$ would be. How do I evaluate that?
Also, out of curiosity, what would $\frac{du}{dx}$ be if instead I substituted $u(x) = \frac{x}{y}$

For $u(x)=y(x)/x$, there holds $y(x)=x\cdot u(x)$. Then $\frac{dy}{dx} = u + x\frac{du}{dx}$.

It's just the chain rule - remember, $y = y(x)$,so you'd be using the quotient rule either way.

Something wrong with the title here.

Based on the proposed substitution, the proposed ODE becomes:
\begin{align*}
y' = \exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) + \frac{y}{x} & \Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{x}{u}\right)' = \exp(u) + \frac{1}{u}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{u - xu'}{u^{2}} = \exp(u) + \frac{1}{u}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u - xu' = u^{2}\exp(u) + u\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{u'}{u^{2}\exp(u)} = -\frac{1}{x} 
\end{align*}
I am afraid there is no solution in terms of elementary functions.

Actually this is $u = x/y$, not $u=y/x$.

@RobertIsrael Indeed, thanks for pointing it out. But both approaches lead to equivalent problems.


However, I am having trouble figuring out what $\tfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}$ would be. How do I evaluate that?

Just apply the product rule (or quotient rule).
$\begin{align}u(x) &= \dfrac{y(x)}{x}\\u'(x) &= \dfrac{xy'(x)-y(x)}{x^2}\\&=\dfrac{x(\mathrm e^{x/y(x)}+y(x)/x)-y(x)}{x^2}\\\dfrac{\mathrm d u(x)}{\mathrm d x}&=\dfrac{\mathrm e^{1/u(x)}}{x}\end{align}$

Also, out of curiosity, what would $\tfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}$ be if instead I substituted $u(x)=x/y$

Now that you know what to do, do that.

If you let first
$$e^{\frac x y}=z \implies y=\frac{x}{\log (z)}$$ the equation becomes
$$x\,z'+z^2\log(z)^2=0$$ Switch variables
$$\frac x {x'}+z^2\log(z)^2=0\qquad \implies \qquad \frac {x'}{x}=-\frac 1 {z^2\log(z)^2}$$
$$\log(x)+C=-\int \frac {dz} {z^2\log(z)^2}$$ One integration by parts to get
$$\log(x)+C=\text{Ei}(-\log (z))+\frac{1}{z \log(z)}$$ which is impossible to inverse.
